# PIL: enlarge an image

Tags: python, resize, transform, python-imaging-library

I'm having trouble getting PIL to enlarge an image.  Large images get scaled down just fine, but small images won't get bigger.

```
# get the ratio of the change in height of this image using the
# by dividing the height of the first image
s = h / float(image.size[1])
# calculate the change in dimension of the new image
new_size = tuple([int(x*s) for x in image.size])
# if this image height is larger than the image we are sizing to
if image.size[1] > h: 
    # make a thumbnail of the image using the new image size
    image.thumbnail(new_size)
    by = "thumbnailed"
    # add the image to the images list
    new_images.append(image)
else:
    # otherwise try to blow up the image - doesn't work
    new_image = image.resize(new_size)
    new_images.append(new_image)
    by = "resized"
logging.debug("image %s from: %s to %s" % (by, str(image.size), str(new_size)))
```

Comment: could you also please write how you did read the image file?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Both `resize` and `transform` methods properly resize images.

```
size_tuple = im.size
x1 = y1 = 0
x2, y2 = size_tuple

# resize
im = im.resize(size_tuple)

# transform
im = im.transform(size_tuple, Image.EXTENT, (x1,y1,x2,y2))
```

If you are having the same problem I described - try it on another machine.  There must be something wrong with the python installation on my server.  It worked fine on my local machine.

Comment: use negative values to center the image:
```
s = 1024
h,w = 768, 512 
x1 = int(s//2) - (w//2)
y1 = int(s//2) - (h//2)
im = im.transform((s, s), Image.EXTENT, (-x1,-y1,s-x1,s-y1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example how to resize an image in every direction with openCV and numpy:

```
import cv2, numpy

original_image = cv2.imread('original_image.jpg',0)
original_height, original_width = original_image.shape[:2]
factor = 2
resized_image = cv2.resize(original_image, (int(original_height*factor), int(original_width*factor)), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC )

cv2.imwrite('resized_image.jpg',resized_image)
#fixed var name
```

Simple as that. You wanna use "cv2.INTER_CUBIC" to enlarge (factor > 1) and "cv2.INTER_AREA" to make the images smaller (factor < 1).

Comment: The OP asked about resizing in the PIL framework, though